# Record a contribution manually over the phone?

Tags: contributions

Pretty rare situation, I would think, but I've had a few people contact us by phone to ask us to manually process a donation for them. I would have thought I could do this under "New Contribution", but it doesn't appear there is a way for me to input their payment details -- just the last 4 digits of their card... Is there a way to complete a payment in the backend admin on behalf of someone else, or do I just use the front-end form for this?

Comment: i think you will need to say what Payment Processor you are using - as the capability of taking a cc payment via backend depends upon this.

Comment: Also note it's kind of a hidden link once you've opened the new contribution form - in the top right. You can also see it on a contact's contribution tab, there's a button about halfway down.

Comment: All the organizations I work with go straight to their payment processor and process the payment there. Then they record it in Civi.

Answer (score 1):

I see now that when I create a contact record, and then go to their Contribution tab there is an option for "Submit Credit Card Contribution"... Seems this should be available on the "New Contribution" page as well, but hey, at least it exists!